# DynamoDB results not equal to object modeling

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have an object model like below.

```
'use strict';
var crypto = require('crypto');
var dynamoose = require('../../config/database');
var Schema = dynamoose.Schema; 
var NavSchema = new Schema({
    client_id: {
        type: String,
        hashKey: true
    },
    code: {
        type: String,
        rangeKey: 'client_id'
    },
    name: String,
    service_group: String,
    search_text : String,
    description : String,
    images : [],
    active : Boolean,
    price : Number,
    staff : [],
    time_period : Number,
    created_date : String,
    modified_date : String
});

 module.exports = dynamoose.model('Services', NavSchema);
```

I do a scan on my doc.It's returning the object by missing most of the attributes.See the query.

```
    exports.getServicesByGroup = function(req, res, next){
Services.scan('service_group').contains(req.body.group.code).where('client_id').eq(app.prepareUserClient(req)).exec(function(err, services) {
            if(err) res.json(err);
            var response = {
                data:services,
                errror:false
            }
            res.json(response);
        });

    }
```

Its returning this object.
`[ NewModel {
    client_id: 'abc',
    code: '001',
    name: 'Feathered Brows',
    service_group: '1',
    time_period: 2 },
  NewModel {
    client_id: 'abc',
    code: '002',
    name: 'Anastasia Brows',
    service_group: '1' }]`

Most of the attributes are missing form the results.What is is the problem with my code.Please help.
[image] Table view on dynamodb console.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the missing attribute on table? Is the attribute name matching? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, sure, Find the image 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY807SSQ6F9RkFSOFNSdElRNVk/view?usp=sharing , https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY807SSQ6F9c0RFWGFNbHdxTkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't access google drive. Please add as a image in OP.

Comment: @notionquest, I have updated the post.

Comment: If the attributes are not present in the item, the output wouldn't have it. For  example, the item 'abc' doesn't have search_text, so it is not present in the output which is as expected. The non-key attributes are not mandatory on all the item. You can expect only key attributes in the output. All other non-key attributes may or may not present

Comment: But why those values are not even getting save on dynamoos ?

Comment: It depends on the save item data. DynamoDB doesn't enforce the non-key attributes to be mandatory. This is similar to NULLABLE fields on RDBMS.